Manhwa in which a female main character transmigrates into a strategy game where she guides one character to be king
It's a manhwa with a female protagonist who was sick in her previous life and loved a strategy game. The game had three routes with different difficulties and the goal was to make one of three male characters the new king.
She picked the hardest difficulty and beat it and then reincarnated in the game as a character that she had used and thrown away strategically. The guy she lead on the hardest difficulty was an idiot and an illegitimate child. Pretty sure he had blue hair. She allies with a duke character with black hair to save herself. He's the guy with medium difficulty. She either had blonde or light pink hair.
The blue-haired idiot suspects that the black-haired Duke has the guide working with him since Blue Hair stopped hearing her voice, but the Duke is making political waves. However, he doesn't suspect the female main character because she's playing dumb in front of him.
Does anyone know this one? It's driving me crazy!
